# jQuery append() not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append the following table built up in a string to a div on my page using this:

```
var table = 
'<table data-custom="3963770" id="table" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5" 
        valign="top" width="995px" border="3" bordercolor="#83725B">

        <th height="50" colspan="2">Company Name</th>
        <th height="50" colspan="3">Esco Number</th>
        <th height="50" colspan="1">Province</th>
        <th height="50">Sector</th>
        <th height="50">Technology</th>
        <th height="50" colspan="2">Status</th>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">3H Envirostrategies cc</td>
        <td colspan="3">11059420</td>
        <td>Gauteng, KZN, Western Cape, Mpumalanga, Free State, 
            Eastern Cape</td>
        <td>
          <select id="mainSectors0">
            <option>Commercial</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="mainTechs0">
            <option>Project Management</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">Active</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border: none;" colspan="5">
          <div data-custom="contact_info" style="display:inline;"><u>Contact information</u></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tbody data-custom="place_holder">
      </tbody>
    </table>';
```

I have a div tag with:

```
<div id="table"></div>
```

I then try to use this to add the table to the div:

```
$(table).appendTo($('#table'));

// I've tried $("#table").append(table); but no luck.
```

It works fine in every other browser except IE 6+. Does anybody know of a workaround, or if i'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Javascript is pretty touchy about multiline strings & I wouldn't rely on them being accepted across browser.. Try it with just var table = "<table></table>"

Comment: Does anything happen at all in IE?  Errors?

Comment: @Pointy nothing happens in any IE browser... just blank, @minikomi I formatted it above for readability, it's all on one line in the code

Comment: Do you still want the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works for me, also on IE : http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/N5z5T/

Are you sure that you use the var-keyword before `table = '<table>....</table';`

If not, this may break IE, see this related topic: [jQuery selector does not work in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528093/jquery-selector-does-not-work-in-ie7-8/6528291#6528291)

Comment: Is there a way to show us your site? Do other jQuery-script work on your site?

Comment: There's no way, other scripts are working fine, and it's only in IE that it's not working

Comment: So I'm afraid we need more code(maybe everything) or a fiddle, the error is not caused by the code you've posted.

Comment: Didn't know that here are PMs available. But if they are, yes you can.

Comment: @Dr.Molle let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1011/discussion-between-mattbh-and-dr-molle)

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle for your help!! Solution: extra <div> tag at the end of the table needed to be removed

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML in `table` variable is invalid. Try to make `$('#table').append('<div>a</div>');`. It works in IE. Make your HTAMl valid.

Comment: Specifically, the row of `<th>` tags is lacking surrounding `<tr>` tags.

Comment: @MattBH, TH is a CELL, not a row. Try to remove your's THs for the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#table').html(table);
```

It uses [jQuery's html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2), which makes a bit more sense in this circumstance than append. Not sure why append isn't working though

Comment: Internally, pretty much exactly the same thing will happen anyway.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah... there's no reason I can think of that this would work over appendTo, but then again, there's no reason I can think of that appendTo wouldn't work. I thought it might be worth ruling out appendTo itself being the problem, which we now have.

Comment: Append will add the element to the existing parent.  This will replace the entire html inside the parent overriding what is currently in there. Not the same.  You could do $('#table').html($('#table').html() + table);

Comment: @JSON - I'm aware that `append` appends and `html` replaces, however from the OP's question, it appears like this is what he is actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to make div as a jquery object when you are using `appentTo`. try fallowing

```
 $(table).appendTo('#table');
```

or

```
$('#table').append(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have multiple elements with the same id "table"?

Comment: Nope tried changing the div's id to tabledata and still no luck.

Comment: @MattBH Have you checked the source after appending (with the developer tool). Perhaps it just doesn't get rendered for some reason.

Comment: i have i've checked the source code and used an alert `alert($('#tabledata').html());` which returned blank

Comment: @MattBH try appending something else. For example do `$('#tabledata').append('<div>foo</div>'); alert($('#tabledata').html());` and check if that works. If it does I have no idea anymore.

Comment: Using iframes? If so, you cannot use pure $ to find something inside the iframe. Also try logging `$('#tabledata')`, `$(table)` etc