# JQuery window.location.hash not supported in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, hash, onchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.location = #anchor doesn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173394/window-location-anchor-doesnt-work-in-ie)

I have a select box which when clicked changes the hash in the URL for my AJAX based page. I have a function that periodically checks window.location.hash for a change then updates the content accordingly. The following code is the function that changes the URL when the select is changed. It works in Firefox but I cannot get it to work in IE! I keep getting an Object doesn't support this property or method error:

#ob is my select

```
$("#ob").change(function() {
   ob = $(this).val();
   window.location.hash = "#ob=" + ob;
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Which IE version did you use? IE7 or below does not support onhashchange event.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the hash, the error happens in the line before.
declare the variable with the var-keyword:

```
$("#ob").change(function() {
   var ob = $(this).val();
   window.location.hash = "#ob=" + ob;
});
```

Read the explanation here: [jQuery selector does not work in IE7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528093/jquery-selector-does-not-work-in-ie7-8/6528291#6528291)

Comment: While good practice, this wouldn't fix the problem.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase: this *shouldn't* fix the problem.  I know IE adds every element's ID as a global property, but from what I remembered, overwriting those wasn't a problem.  [I did some testing](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/zNhwK/), and oddly enough, just assigning to the global `ob` does indeed throw.  However, if you first overwrite `window.ob`, then this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rolling your own state management, I'd just go with a battle-tested library to handle everything for you.  My favorite is [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).

```
$("#ob").change(function() {
   var ob = $(this).val();
   $.bbq.pushState({ ob:ob });
});
```

As an added bonus, BBQ hooks in to modern browsers' [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event rather than polling for changes to `location.hash`.